# Problems with multilingual site

Tags: wordpress, wpml

I use the WPML plugin to make my site multilingual. But some parts of the site are not displayed in the second language of the site. What's the problem?

Comment: You can found a solution in WPML site, but basically the question is, do you created all content in this second language? WPML has an option to hide elements when the content in other languages doesn't exist. More specific question will be appreciated.

Comment: All The content of all pages has been translated.